# Allowing users to view GPU utilization in GCP Vertex AI training jobs

Tags: google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am running custom training jobs using Google cloud Vertex AI. But when I enter a custom training job page, the GPU utilization display is not shown, instead, there is a message saying "you don't have access to this data."
[image]
I would appreciate help finding the right IAM role which will allow me to view the GPU utilization.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`monitoring.viewer`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control#mon_roles_desc) IAM role to display both CPU and GPU utilization in GCP Vertex AI training jobs on top of [`aiplatform.viewer`](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control#predefined-roles) IAM role.

[image]